# Bootstrap error while compiling GCC 4.8.0

Tags: linux, compile, gcc

I'm getting bootstrap errors while trying to install GCC and could use some help.  I'm trying to compile GCC in my home directory on a shared system (cluster).  The cluster has GCC 4.4.3, which I'm using to bootstrap the compilation. I wrote this little script to show what I'm doing and to help in debugging:

```
# Installation parameters
gccver=4.8.0
gmpver=5.1.1
mpcver=1.0.1
mpfrver=3.1.2
prefix=$HOME/local
langs=c,c++

# Download source
wget ftp://gnu.mirror.iweb.com/gnu/gcc/gcc-${gccver}/gcc-${gccver}.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-${gmpver}.tar.bz2
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpc/mpc-${mpcver}.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpfr/mpfr-${mpfrver}.tar.gz

# Unpack source
tar -xzvf gcc-${gccver}.tar.gz
tar -xjvf gmp-${gmpver}.tar.bz2
tar -xzvf mpc-${mpcver}.tar.gz
tar -xzvf mpfr-${mpfrver}.tar.gz

# Move dependency source directories into gcc source directory
mv gmp-${gmpver} gcc-${gccver}/gmp
mv mpc-${mpcver} gcc-${gccver}/mpc
mv mpfr-${mpfrver} gcc-${gccver}/mpfr

# create a build directory and change to it
mkdir objdir
pushd objdir

# configure, make, check, and install gcc:
../gcc-${gccver}/configure --prefix=${prefix} --enable-languages=${langs}
make -j 16
make install

# return to the original directory
popd
```

The above fails during 'make' with the error: "Bootstrap comparison failure!" I've uploaded the last few pages of output as [error.txt](http://myweb.dal.ca/~dstaple/error.txt), and also [config.log](http://myweb.dal.ca/~dstaple/config.log) from the configure stage. I've tried:

1. running `make distclean` from objdir and re-running configure and make.
2. removing `-j 16` from `make`.
3. using an absolute path when calling configure.
4. using the `contrib/download_prerequisites` script to download
   mpfr-2.4.2, gmp-4.3.2, and mpc-0.8.1, instead of the newer versions
   above.
5. setting the PWDCMD environment variable to an automounter-aware pwd
   command (pawd).
6. bootstrapping with a different version of GCC (3.4.6).
7. bootstrapping with ICC 12.0.0 via `export CC=icc` and `export CXX=icpc`.

I also tried posting this question to the gcc mailing list; that's where I received the suggestion (2) above.

Any idea why this build is failing?

Comment: The last few lines of the error message, from `Entering directory` onwards, are because `make install` is called even though `make` failed. It'd probably be a better idea to call `make && make install` instead of calling them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `make bootstrap` or `make bootstrap4` instead of directly `make install`, to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: It's not clear to me [from the GCC build instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html) what the difference is between `make` and `make bootstrap`; for me it seems that `make` anyway performs a 3-stage bootstrap. Also, does `bootstrap4` include the same first three stages as `bootstrap`, in which case I should expect it to fail? I'll anyway try them both when I get home from work.

Comment: `make bootstrap` and `make bootstrap4` both give the same error as `make`. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform `make distclean` and `./configure && make` again.

See similar problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651547/error-compiling-the-compiler-gcc

Comment: I tried this and it didn't make a difference. I saw that advice floating around, but `make distclean` deletes everything in my objdir (except one of the stage files), so it's the same as starting over for me. Also, I'm not doing a `./configure` because gcc doesn't support building in the source tree; I run configure and make from an objdir outside the gcc source tree.

Answer (score 0):

A Chuck Norris builder that's in charge of the system built GCC 4.8.0 using the following steps:

```
module purge
cd /tmp/repoman
tar xzf ~/src/gnu/gcc-4.8.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.8.0/
tar xzf ~/src/gnu/mpfr-2.4.2.tar.gz
ln -s mpfr-2.4.2 mpfr
tar xzf ~/src/gnu/gmp-4.3.2.tar.gz
ln -s gmp-4.3.2 gmp
tar xzf ~/src/gnu/mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz
ln -s mpc-0.8.1 mpc
cd ../
mkdir objdir
cd objdir/
../gcc-4.8.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0 CC=gcc4 CXX=g++4
make && make install
```

This is quite similar to what I was doing. The differences were that I didn't do a `module purge`, I `mv`'d the prerequisite sources instead of `ln -s`'ing them, I didn't specify `CC=gcc4 CXX=g++4`, and obviously my `--prefix` pointed to a path in my home directory.  I'm not sure which of these would've made the difference; probably either `CC=... CXX=...` or `module purge`. I will test and post the result.